# Unable to access portal using IP address from Amazon EC2 windows instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, liferay

I deployed a Liferay portal on Amazon EC2 windows instance how to access that on client browsers, as I am trying using public IP address but it is giving message it can't be reached.

Comment: Check your instance security groups.

Comment: I checked it everything seems to be ok as per different blogs I studied. My tomcat port is 8080

Comment: What ip is the service bound to? Often with a tomcat service, you put it behind a web server instead of allowing access directly.

Answer (score 1):

In order:

1. Make sure the service is working (telnet locally on 127.0.0.1 8080)
2. Make sure your instance has a public IP address
3. Modify the local instance firewall to allow traffic on 8080 (or disable the local firewall)

4.Configure the instance's security group to allow traffic on 8080

If all of above conditions are met, then it MUST work :)

Answer (score 1):

There Few Things Which You Can Check and I think Can be Issue for Windows EC2 Instance.

1) Allow Specific Port In Security Group in AWS .

2) Then You Must allow that port in Windows Firewall ( Create a Rule )
Refer : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753558.aspx